# ggmap: removing country names from Google's terrain map

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying plotting points on a map using ggmap, but I don't know how to remove the names of countries from the background of a map

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
map <- get_map(location = 'place', zoom = 4)
read.table("latlon.txt", header = TRUE) -> tbl
plot<-ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), color=tbl$color, size=3, data = tbl) + theme(legend.position = "none")+
  #geom_text(aes(label=pop),data=tbl,hjust=0, vjust=0)
  ggsave(plot=plot,height=7.5,width=11, filename="map.pdf", useDingbats=FALSE)
plot(plot)
```

I want to enable labels on my points, but the background text basically gets in the way. Does anyone know how I can keep the Google terrain map but drop the country names? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried some of the other maptypes available in http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/get_map

Comment: See this question on how to superimpose map images [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307896/using-ggplots-ggmap-function-to-superimpose-two-maps-on-top-of-each-other/36350137#36350137). Use one map for the background, add your geom_point, and then use `inset_ggmap` to place the labels on top.

Comment: Try `terrain-background` and `terrain-labels`.  See [here](http://maps.stamen.com/#terrain/12/37.7706/-122.3782) for more map types. For the location, you can use Google Maps to locate the point of interest, right click, and select 'what's here' to get the longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this question is no longer relevant for the questioner, but I ran into the same problem today, searched a bit and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018703/adjust-font-size-in-map-plots-in-ggmap) where the questioner has a similar problem and someone gave a very useful answer with the hint to the [style syntax of Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling#features).

So, when you use `get_googlemap` instead of the wrapper `get_map`, you can put an extra `style` argument, e.g.:

```
    map <- get_googlemap(center = 'middle east', zoom = 4,
                 style = 'feature:administrative.country|element:labels|visibility:off')
    plot <- ggmap(map)
    print(plot)
```

There are more features and elements, which you can remove or change, but just the country labels can simply be removed with the code above.

Comment: Note also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41051499/5977215) that shows an issue and solution to using a vector of styles

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
map <- get_googlemap(center ="middle east", zoom = 4, 
       style=c(feature="administrative.country",element="labels",visibility="off"))

plot <- ggmap(map)

print(plot)
```