# Making Multiple Style References In Google Maps API

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I cannot figure out how to make multiple style references in one `ggmap()` query from the Google Maps API in R.

Making one query is simple:

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_googlemap("new york city", 
                     zoom = 12, 
                     maptype = "roadmap", 
                     style = c(feature = "poi.medical", 
                               element = "geometry", 
                               color = "red"))
ggmap(map)
```

But let's say I want to make all parks blue as well as hospitals red. How would I go about doing that?

I have tried nested concatenation within my style variable, but that doesn't work. Also, if I make two separate style arguments, I get the following error:

```
formal argument "style" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

(For reference, parks are `poi.park` in the Google Maps API, element is again "geometry", and color would be "blue".)

In the Google Maps API reference, they state that you can easily make multiple JSON declarations nested within one argument:

> Style rules are applied in the order that you specify. Do not combine
>   multiple operations into a single style operation. Instead, define
>   each operation as a separate entry in the style array.

How can I do this in R?

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you have any questions or need any clarification!

Comment: weird - the source code suggests this should be possible by passing the items as a list although when I tried it only plotted the last one https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/get_googlemap.R#L219

Comment: @Jacob - there certainly is something fishy with the way the `style` argument handles lists

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is a combination of poor documenation, plus a bug in ggmap.

### Explanation

If you look at the example on [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling) you see that styles are separated by `&style=`

> &style=feature:road.local%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0x00ff00&style=feature:landscape%7Celement:geometry.fill%7Ccolor:0x000000&style=element:labels%7Cinvert_lightness:true

So in your example, if you wanted your two styles

```
style1 <- c(feature = "poi.medical", element = "geometry", color = "red")
style2 <- c(feature = "poi.park", element = "geometry", color = "blue")
```

This woud look something like

> &style=feature:poi.medical|element:geometry|color:red&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|color:blues

In `?get_googlemap`, for the `style` argument it says

> character string to be supplied directly to the api for the style argument or a named vector (see examples)

And in the [source code](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/get_googlemap.R#L219) we see that it can also supposedly handle lists. So if we create a list out of our styles we get

```
style <- list(style1, style2)
```

Which, when run through the `get_googlemap` gives the url

```
map <- get_googlemap("new york city", 
                        zoom = 12, 
                        maptype = "roadmap", 
                        style = style)
```

> ...&style=style=c(%22poi.medical%22,%20%22geometry%22,%20%22red%22)&style=c(%22poi.park%22,%20%22geometry%22,%20%22blue%22)&sensor=false

Which is also incorrect.

And similarly for a concatenated vector of styles we get an incorrectly formatted URL

```
style <- c(style1, style2)

map <- get_googlemap("new york city", 
                        zoom = 12, 
                        maptype = "roadmap", 
                        style = style)
```

> ...&style=feature:poi.medical%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:red%7Cfeature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:blue&sensor=false

### Solution

Force it to use a `&sytle=` value as the first (unnamed) element in the 2nd (and subsequent) style vector, and concatenate them using `c()`, rather than `list()`

```
style1 <- c(feature = "poi.medical", element = "geometry", color = "red")
style2 <- c("&style=", feature = "poi.park", element = "geometry", color = "blue")

style <- c(style1, style2)

map <- get_googlemap("new york city", 
                        zoom = 12, 
                        maptype = "roadmap", 
                        style = style)

plot(map)
```

[image]

---

And now a separate plug for my gooleway package, where you can specify the style using JSON, and the map is interactive

```
library(googleway)

style <- '[{"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#00FF00"}]},{"featureType":"poi.medical","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#FF00FF"}]}]'

map_key <- "you_need_an_api_key"

google_map(key = map_key, location = c(40.7128, -74.0059), 
                     zoom = 13, height = 800, 
                     styles = style)
```

Comment: Great solution! Will defintely have a look at googleway!

Comment: @SymbolixAU - Thanks for your hard work and thorough explanation! Is this the kind of thing that you would suggest I, or you, submit as a bug to the ggmap github repo so they are aware of it?

Comment: @medavis6 - yes I reckon so; I like to know when people find issues with my package and I'm sure they would too.