# Re-color google terrain map in R

Tags: r, colors, maps, elevation, levelplot

I have created a terrain map of my region of interest using:

```
library(dismo)
library(rasterVis)
gm = gmap(extent(c(-155.0181, -39.61941, 41.68144, 85.1355)),zoom=NULL,type="terrain",lonlat=TRUE,scale=2)
gm <- trim(gm)

e6 <- extent(-141, -96, 46.99998, 70.0)
e6pol <- as(e6, 'SpatialPolygons')
centroid <- coordinates(e6pol)

library(Cairo)
Cairo(file="whatever.png", 
      type="png",
      units="in", 
      width=4, 
      height=4, 
      pointsize=12*96/72, 
      dpi=1000)

levelplot(gm,maxpixel=ncell(gm),panel=panel.levelplot.raster,col.regions=gm@legend@colortable,
          interpolate=TRUE,colorkey=F,margin=FALSE,at=0:255,xlab=list(label="Longitude",cex=1),yscale.components = yscale.raster.subticks,
          xscale.components = xscale.raster.subticks,
          ylab=list(label="Latitude",cex=1),scales=list(x=list(cex=1),y=list(cex=1)),
          par.settings=list(axis.line=list(lwd=1.2), strip.border=list(lwd=1.2)),
          xlim=c(-155.0997, -76.0997),ylim=c(39.09998, 80.09997 ))
dev.off()
```

This gives me the plot below:

[image]

How can one chnage the colors such that water bodies are darkblue and land areas are `green` to `gray`, for example? Also add a colorkey.

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto that's not quite true. Google allows you to change all the colours of the map. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41051499/5977215) for doing it in ggmap, [Google's style wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) for creating your own styles, and [Google's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Comment: @SymbolixAU Well.... one always learn new things... ;-)  I really thought it wasn't possible. Sorry if my comment was misleading ! I'll remove it.

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto - that's why we're all here :)

Comment: @SymbolixAU I agree ! By the way: your `googleway` package seems the perfect solution for the question.