# How to get only street labels with get_googlemap

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I´m trying to get only the street labels from Google Maps API using `get_googlemap()`from the `ggmap` package. I read Google Static Maps Developer and also [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling) and managed to get rid of the labels of the adminsitrative feature by specifying `style = "feature:administrative|visibility:off"`

```
cntr <- c(-71.445, -33.055)
map <- get_googlemap(location = "Chile", center = cntr, 
                 zoom = 13, source = "google", 
                 maptype ="roadmap", color = "bw",
                 style = "feature:administrative|visibility:off")
mapplot <- ggmap(map)
```

But I´m still struggling to just get the map with the street labels. Is there a way to do it? or get_googlemap doesn't support that option? I have tried with `style = "feature:landscape|visibility:off"` but nothing changes, when I use `style = "feature:landscape|element:geometry|visibility:off"` I get this:

[image: style = "feature:landscape|element:geometry|visibility:off"]

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected result is - what's wrong with the map you've got? Also note that if you intend to use multiple style options take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41051499/5977215)

Comment: What I expect is just the street layer of the map, with no other attribute except for the streets and their label, something like figure 5 in [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/mcgillnrscgis2banlakieva/lab-reports/lab2).

Comment: have a play with the [styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) - if you chose the 'silver' theme, and make the roads red you'll get pretty close to the image in your link.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that tool