# How to change size of features in ggmap (R package)

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to bold or increase size of rivers or topographic features in google map in R. I used ggmap to plot the map with this code:

```
geo<-read.table()
geo
station Latitude Longitude 
1   37.007995   50.433255   
2   36.990172   50.434971   
3   36.964116   50.435658

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(range(geo$Longitude)),
                            lat = mean(range(geo$Latitude))),
               zoom = 13, scale = "auto",
               maptype = "toner", language = "en-EN")

map_plot <- ggmap(map, darken=c(.2,"gray")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),
             data = geo,
             colour = "red", size=4, pch=20, bg=10)

map_plot + geom_line(size=1)
```

but the result is not what I desire. some other lines which did not belong to the map were bold.

See the attached map:

[image: map]

Is there any codes in ggmap that increase or bold map features?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you could use a shapefile of the river/waterways, it's hard to say any more without example data we don't have access to `geo` :(  `get_map` is using base map tiles to initiate the plotting area, so maybe you could find a better provider

Comment: @Nate Thank you. But I don,t have access to the shapefile of the area. <geo> is a dataframe which contains just 3 geographic point.

Comment: great, so would you add it in your example so it's reproducible? Also I don't see any topographic features in your map layer. What would be your expected behavior?

Comment: I added <geo> dataframe into the example. I used "toner" maptype. topographic features are available in "terrain" maptype. I would like to bold the narrow lines (near to the red points) in the map (which shows rivers in this map)

Comment: You can customise the style of a map, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051499/5977215)

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks a lot. But the problem is that I want to use <get_map>  function. Customizing the style of a map is available in the <get_googlemap> function.