# Styled Google Maps with ggmap() / get_googlemap() in R

Tags: r, google-maps

I would like to use the tool "Styling Wizard" from Google maps to create specific map styles in R.
(https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

The Style Wizard is easy to use for a programming novice like me and puts out a piece of code called JSON, which apparently can be used in R to tell the get_googlemap() function how to create a specific styled map. 
This is described in detail in this blog post from 2015:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-styled-google-maps-in-ggmap/

I was trying to adapt this strategy, however somethings must have changed since and the piece of code described on the blog does not work anymore (or does not work when I run it?).

**To specify I get the warning message:
"`panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead"
and the produced map looks not at all as desired. [see picture here, left side is how it should be, right side is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fVOt.png)**

Any ideas / hints what needs tweaking to make this work?

(Yes, I know that the get_googlemap() function has the argument "style" which can specify these things, its just hard and elaborate to use and I thought if there is a way to utilize the Style Wizard from Google maps, it would be very nice!)

Thanks everyone

I am using exactly the same code as described in the blog post here (https://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-styled-google-maps-in-ggmap/):

```
library("RJSONIO")
library("ggmap")
library("magrittr")
style <- '[
  {
"stylers": [
  { "saturation": -100 },
  { "gamma": 0.5 }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ff0000" }
]
  }
]'
style_list <- fromJSON(style, asText=TRUE)
create_style_string<- function(style_list){
  style_string <- ""
  for(i in 1:length(style_list)){
    if("featureType" %in% names(style_list[[i]])){
  style_string <- paste0(style_string, "feature:", 
                         style_list[[i]]$featureType, "|")      
}
elements <- style_list[[i]]$stylers
a <- lapply(elements, function(x)paste0(names(x), ":", x)) %>%
       unlist() %>%
       paste0(collapse="|")
style_string <- paste0(style_string, a)
if(i < length(style_list)){
  style_string <- paste0(style_string, "&style=")       
}
  }  
  # google wants 0xff0000 not #ff0000
  style_string <- gsub("#", "0x", style_string)
  return(style_string)
}
    style_string <- create_style_string(style_list)
mymap <- ggmap(get_googlemap("chicago", size=c(800,800), 
style=style_string), extent="device")
ggsave(filename="pics/mymap.png", width=8, height=8)
```

Comment: where is the error? why does not work? place error code or pics , or check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Multiple Style References In Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049782/making-multiple-style-references-in-google-maps-api) - I give a detailed explanation on styling `ggmap`, plus an alternative using `googelway`

Comment: I added a picture and the warning message I get, so maybe now it is easier to identify what is amiss!

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to create the map? This would make it easier to debug your issue.

Comment: same code as on the blog, I added it (sorry for the bad formatting)